# How can i separate a full name?

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I've to take the right part and clean it after it comparate with the middle part and save if are equal

```
> #!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'levenshtein'
require 'csv'

# Extending String class for blank? method
class String
  def blank?
    self.strip.empty?
  end
end

# In
lines = CSV.read('entrada.csv')
lines.each do |line|
  id      = line[0].upcase.strip
  left    = line[1].upcase.strip
  right   = line[2].upcase.strip
  eduardo = line[2].upcase.split(' ','de')

  line[0] = id
  line[1] = left
  line[2] = right
  line[4] = eduardo[0]+eduardo[1]

  distance = Levenshtein.distance left, right

  line << 99 if (left.blank? or right.blank?)
  line << distance unless (left.blank? or right.blank?)
end

# Out
# counter = 0
CSV.open('salida.csv', 'w') do |csv|
  lines.each do |line|
    # counter = counter + 1 if line[3] <= 3
    csv << line
  end
end

# p counter
```

The middle is the correct the rigth i should correct

Some examples:

- Eduardo | Abner | Herrera | Herrera -> Eduardo Herrera
- Angel | De | Leon -> Angel De Leon
- Maira | Angelina | de | Leon -> Maira De Leon
- Marquilla | Gutierrez | Petronilda |De | Leon -> Marquilla Petronilda

Comment: _Sidenote:_ I have no idea what you are asking about, but I strongly believe, that Levenstein’s distance has nothing to do with your task.

Comment: yes said the different for example in spanish we have some full name including the married lastname from the husband so i have to separate the first name and last name and including the married for example (Elena de Herrera)

Comment: Could you provide clear examples of inputs and outputs? Like `'Michael George Schwern'` -> `{ first: 'Michael', middle: 'George', last: 'Schwern' }`.

Comment: Do you only target spanish names? What about other names schemas? I advise to read: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: How can you possibly expect to get "Olga Chiru" from "Olga de Gil"? No amount of string juggling will help you here.

Comment: because the correct data is the middle and the wrong data is the right because we take data in two situation both from differents sites.

Comment: If you cannot describe the logic you are trying to implement, it is not possible to write the code to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

First order of business is to come up with some rules. Based on your examples, and [Spanish naming customs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_naming_customs#Naming_system_in_Spain), here's my stab at the rules.

- A name has a forename, paternal surname, and optional maternal surname.
- A forename can be multiple words.
- A surname can be multiple words linked by a `de`, `y`, or `e`.

So `['Marquilla', 'Gutierrez', 'Petronilda', 'De', 'Leon']` should be `{ forename: 'Marquilla', paternal_surname: 'Gutierrez', maternal_surname: 'Petronilda de Leon' }`

To simplify the process, I'd first join any composite surnames into one field. `['Marquilla', 'Gutierrez', 'Petronilda', 'De', 'Leon']` becomes `['Marquilla', 'Gutierrez', 'Petronilda De Leon']`. Watch out for cases like `['Angel', 'De', 'Leon']` in which case the surname is probably `De Leon`.

Once that's done, figuring out which part is which becomes easier.

```
name = {}

if parts.length == 1
    error?
# The special case of only two parts: forename paternal_surname
elsif parts.length == 2
    name = {
        forename: parts[0],
        paternal_surname: parts[1]
    }
# forename paternal_surname maternal_surname
else
    # The forename can have multiple parts, so work from the
    # end and whatever's left is their forename.
    name[:maternal_surname] = parts.pop
    name[:paternal_surname] = parts.pop
    name[:forename] = parts.join(" ")
end
```

There's *a lot* of ambiguity in Spanish naming, so this can only be an educated guess at what their actual name is. You'll probably have to tweak the rules as you learn more about the dataset. For example, I'm pretty sure handling of `de` is not that simple. For example...

> One Leocadia Blanco Álvarez, married to a Pedro Pérez Montilla, may be addressed as Leocadia Blanco de Pérez or as Leocadia Blanco Álvarez de Pérez

In that case `['Marquilla', 'Gutierrez', 'Petronilda', 'De', 'Leon']` becomes `['Marquilla', 'Gutierrez', 'Petronilda', 'De Leon']` which is `{ forename: 'Marquilla', paternal_surname: 'Gutierrez', maternal_surname: 'Petronilda', married_to: 'Leon' }` or `'Marquilla Gutierrez Petronilda` who is married to someone whose parental surname is `Leon`.

Good luck.

Comment: okay for example i separate when they're more than 4 spaces and it's easy take first name and last name but what i should i do if i got the De?
for example http://imgur.com/a/qfpS1 so i have to separate and comparated with the correct if are equal save it's not equal search the equal anybody can help me?

Comment: @e.herrera Before trying to figure out which part is which, scan the parts for `de` or other conjunctions and concatenate it with what follows. `['Foo', 'Bar', 'De', 'Baz']` becomes `['Foo', 'Bar', 'De Baz']`. THEN figure out which part is which.

Answer (score -1):

I would add more columns to the database, like `last_name1`, `last_name2`, `last_name3`, etc, and make them optional (don't put validations on those attributes). Hope that answers your question!

Comment: I think the question is about _normalizing_ names in some way, not simply breaking them apart.

Comment: I am curious to read about possible solutions others are proposing :)

Comment: Regarding your suggestion, that is not a good way to store a name. See the link spickermann posted above. Whenever you assume _anything_ about names, there __will__ be users that will violate that assumption. For example, Pablo Picasso's full name is Pablo Diego José Francisco de Paula Juan Nepomuceno María de los Remedios Cipriano de la Santísima Trinidad Ruiz y Picasso. Good luck anticipating that. :)

Comment: So if adding columns in the database to persist is not a good way to store names, what would be your solution?

Comment: Solution to what? I don't think the OP is asking how to _store_ the names. Although I'm not sure what is it that he asks. Regarding storage, I'd store everything in one field.

Comment: Right. But how would you separate the 9348598345 names one has? (I believe that is what he is asking? How to separate a string of many names). Hopefully, Picasso never uses one of my apps ;)

Comment: Separating is trivial. Just split by a whitespace :)

Comment: I don't believe white spaces are allowed in the db, persistence-wise...?

Comment: http://www.mikeperham.com/2012/05/05/five-common-rails-mistakes/  See comment at bottom "Trailing whitespace should never be allowed" (this was my understanding for correct schema architecture)

Comment: @Maddie That's talking about code style, not database values.